# Create IBM AppID instance in IBM Cloud via Ansible - Graduated tier

Tags: ibm-appid

I have been trying to follow the ansible documentation here https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/ansible-collection-ibm/tree/master/examples/appid-instance-creation#configuration-parameters to create an instance of  AppID on IBM Cloud with "Graduated" tier plan_type but getting the below error.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 1, "resource": {"_name": "ansible_testinstance2", "_type": "ibm_resource_instance", "target": "ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2"}, "stderr": "\nError: [ERROR] Error retrieving deployment for plan graduated tier : Request failed with status code: 404, ServerErrorResponse: {"message":"Get object request for an invalid id : deployment","code":404,"global_transaction_id":"gend-1243016054006513672"}\n\n\n  on ibm_resource_instance_ansible_testinstance2.tf line 1, in resource "ibm_resource_instance" "ansible_testinstance2":\n   1: resource ibm_resource_instance "ansible_testinstance2" {\n\n\n", "stderr_lines": ["", "Error: [ERROR] Error retrieving deployment for plan graduated tier : Request failed with status code: 404, ServerErrorResponse: {"message":"Get object request for an invalid id : deployment","code":404,"global_transaction_id":"gend-1243016054006513672"}", "", "", "  on ibm_resource_instance_ansible_testinstance2.tf line 1, in resource "ibm_resource_instance" "ansible_testinstance2":", "   1: resource ibm_resource_instance "ansible_testinstance2" {", "", ""], "stdout": "ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2: Creating...\n", "stdout_lines": ["ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2: Creating..."]}

Does the module support only "lite" plan_type ? I have tried with "graduated tier" , "standard" but to no avail.

Thanks

Tried executing create appid playbook with "graduted" tier.

Expected:

A running instance of AppID

Actual result:

Below error

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 1, "resource": {"_name": "ansible_testinstance2", "_type": "ibm_resource_instance", "target": "ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2"}, "stderr": "\nError: [ERROR] Error retrieving deployment for plan graduated tier : Request failed with status code: 404, ServerErrorResponse: {"message":"Get object request for an invalid id : deployment","code":404,"global_transaction_id":"gend-1243016054006513672"}\n\n\n  on ibm_resource_instance_ansible_testinstance2.tf line 1, in resource "ibm_resource_instance" "ansible_testinstance2":\n   1: resource ibm_resource_instance "ansible_testinstance2" {\n\n\n", "stderr_lines": ["", "Error: [ERROR] Error retrieving deployment for plan graduated tier : Request failed with status code: 404, ServerErrorResponse: {"message":"Get object request for an invalid id : deployment","code":404,"global_transaction_id":"gend-1243016054006513672"}", "", "", "  on ibm_resource_instance_ansible_testinstance2.tf line 1, in resource "ibm_resource_instance" "ansible_testinstance2":", "   1: resource ibm_resource_instance "ansible_testinstance2" {", "", ""], "stdout": "ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2: Creating...\n", "stdout_lines": ["ibm_resource_instance.ansible_testinstance2: Creating..."]}

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out . We need to set plan_type as "graduated-tier" in vars.yml.
Retrieved this info by manually creating an AppID instance and retrieving the plan details of the service by using below command

```
    ibmcloud resource service-instance <name_of_appid>
```

thanks